# How do I change functionality if image is clicked and changes to other image

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

```
sound.setOnClickListener {
        sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mute)
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean)
        mediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
        mediaPlayer!!.start()
    }
```

There is a image name sound which when clicked starts playing a sound of ocean and changes the drawable to mute icon and when clicked on the mute image it stops playing audio. Please help me implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   var playing = false
    var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = null
    sound.setOnClickListener {
            playing = !playing
            var imgResId = if (playing){
               R.drawable.ic_mute
            } else{
               R.drawable.ic_play
            }
            sound.setImageResource(imgResId)
            if (mediaPlayer == null){ 
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean)
                mediaPlayer?.isLooping = true
                 mediaPlayer?.start()
           }else{
               if (playing){
                 mediaPlayer?.stop()
               } else {
                 mediaPlayer?.start()
               }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey Pavel. Thank you for your response. The icon is changing but the audio is not stoping if clicked on mute icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ToggleButton, this is more indicated for your problem because you have two status, on/off

```
    val toggle = ToggleButton(this)
    
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->  
        if (isChecked){ 
            //icon play
            //sound off
        } else {
            //icon mute
            //sound on
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey appersiano, i can't implement it because the sound button is an image.